# Is ImageIO.read() asynchronous?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Is this call supposed to be blocking, in the sense that it's guaranteed that after its execution "all" the stream has been read?

```
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

I was playing with a FilterInputStream that sits between the call `ImageIO.read()` argument and the "real" source (say, a FileInputStream), assuming the above, but there seems to be some race conditions - difficult to reproduce. Sometimes the stream appears only half  consumed after the statement execution.

There is a second related doubt: the definition of "all" the image stream can be ambiguous, consider for example  PNG image that, after the pixel data can have some extra metadata (before the IEND chunk that signals the true end of the image stream). Can I expect that `ImageIO.read()` will read (apart from race conditions) all the image,  or can it happen that the method only consumes what it need to get the pixels values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `ImageIO` API does not say anything about this.  It does explicitly guarantee that the image loading process will be completed.  However, since there is nothing in the API of the `BufferedImage` class that deals with asynchronous loading (like some `isLoaded()` method), it is reasonable to assume that if there is asynchronous loading going on behind the scenes, it *should* be transparent.  (And if not, that's a bug in the implementation!)

Anyway, the way to address your suspicions is to look at the source code of the image reader.  If it is designed to do asynchronous loading, it will be obvious.

(I suspect that the problem is elsewhere.  Maybe your filter stream or the stream it is filtering are not thread-safe and you've got multiple application threads trying to use it / them?)

> Can I expect that ImageIO.read() will read (apart from race conditions) all the image, or can it happen that the method only consumes what it need to get the pixels values?

I don't think you can assume that `ImageIO.read()` will read the entire stream.  It is not part of the spec, and (in general) it is inefficient to read more than is necessary to populate the `BufferedImage`.

Comment: You seem right in both respects. My problem was due to the second issue; not a bug but... "[it's ] inefficient to read more than is necessary to populate", well, strictly speaking, a PNG without an IEND chunk is malformed, but I guess nobody really checks these things...

Comment: @leonbloy - Another way to say what I said is that it is inefficient to do extra validation that the application program doesn't need.  If the application only needs the image part, the validity of the stuff that comes afterwards *is probably* immaterial.  (Indeed, the PNG format designers probably put that stuff at the end so that you could *avoid* reading / parsing it in most cases.)